# Como usar reflection em um objeto COM?

Tags: c#, string, reflexão

estou tentando fazer um reflection em um programa, porém, na hora de pegar o tipo do objeto (Que é necessário para o reflection) está retornando "System.__COMObject", e isto não é útil. O método que eu tentei foi o seguinte:

`Type tipo = simObjects.GetType();`

O mesmo retorno acontece quando eu tento com o método typeof();
Eu pesquisei e encontrei o seguinte método:

`Type tipo = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(simObjects);`

Ele retorna o tipo certo, porém em formato de string, (ele da erro no código acima "Cannot implicit convert "String" to "System.Type", mas eu troquei Type por String e ele retornou o nome do tipo) algum gênio pode me informar como eu consigo retornar em forma de Type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode não ter ficado tão claro o que eu queria, mas eu consegui resolver meio que forçando a reflexão e acabou que não houve a necessidade de pegar o tipo.

```
foreach(PropertyDescriptor descricao in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(ObjetoCOM))
{
    if(descricao.Name == "Nome do atributo")
    {
        foreach(PropertyDescriptor descricao2 in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(descricao))
        {
           if(descricao.Name == "Nome do atributo")
           {
           }
        } 
    }
}
```

Este código retorna os nome dos atributos, por exemplo, se o meu ObjetoCOM tiver os seguites atributos:

```
int idade;
string nome;
Filho filho;
```

e filho tiver:

```
int idade;
string nome;
```

no primeiro laço, o descricao.Name vai ser "idade", "nome" e "filho", e no segundo,(supondo que a condição dê verdadeira com o filho), "idade" e "nome".

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível.

`System.__COMObject` é uma classe declarada como `internal` e todos os seus métodos são expostos por `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`. Assim sendo, esta classe nada mais é que um wrapper para o objeto COM, não possuindo um tipo .Net derivado que possa ser obtido pelo método `Object.GetType()`.

Se quiser ver mais sobre esta classe, recomendo que dê uma olhada no código fonte:

- Mono: [System.__COMObject.cs](https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/__ComObject.Original.cs)
- .NET: [System.__COMObject.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/__comobject.cs)

**Edição:**

De acordo com seu comentário, o que você quer então é pegar RTTI da biblioteca COM. C# não permite este tipo de interação direta com RTTI de objetos não gerenciáveis, então o que fazer?

**1.** Qual a linguagem que sua biblioteca COM foi escrita. Normalmente é C++, mas pode ser escrita em Object Pascal também, por exemplo.

**2.** A biblioteca COM foi compilada com RTTI? Se não, não há nada que possa ser feito a não ser chorar para os desenvolvedores da biblioteca compilarem ela com RTTI. Porque? Porque sem RTTI, simplesmente não há como fazer reflection de um objeto.

**3.** Construa uma biblioteca na mesma linguagem que sua biblioteca COM que faça a reflection por você. Utilizando P/Invoke você interage com ela dentro do C#. Note que mesmo assim você nunca terá um objeto do tipo `System.Type`, pois este objeto só existe em códigos gerenciáveis, que não é o caso da sua biblioteca COM.

Talvez só de construir uma estrutura que encapsule o `std::type_info` retornado pelo operador `typeid` (se for C++ a linguagem da biblioteca COM, claro), e construir os métodos para obter este valor da sua classe COM já seja o suficiente.

A biblioteca de análise RTTI não é complicada não (ou não me parece em um primeiro momento), e precisa de apenas alguns poucos métodos implementados, de acordo com sua necessidade. Comparada com as outras soluções que apresentei nos comentários, ela é uma fração da complexidade/esforço, sem dúvida.

Comment: Você sabe se existe outra forma de retornar o tipo de um objeto da classe `System.__COMObject`? com o segundo código ele retornou certo, porém em forma de string, e não de Type, como eu preciso..

Comment: Crie seus próprios tipos vazios então, e faça um mapa de strings para seus tipos. Problema meio resolvido (McGyver ficaria orgulhoso).

Comment: Eu preciso do tipo, na forma de Type, para fazer o reflection, eu criar um mapa de strings com os tipos não ajuda, entendeu?

Comment: +1 pelo McGyver! Seria necessário escrever um wrapper em MSIL para cada classe COM utilizada. Este wrapper poderia ser feito em C# ou em MSIL. Os dois são um trabalho tão grande quanto a quantidade de classes COM que você manipula e a complexidade das relações entre elas. Ambas poderiam ser feitas em runtime, inclusive (a versão em MSIL é mais apropriada neste caso). Qual o uso específico que você deseja? Pode ser que exista outra abordagem para solucionar seu problema maior.

Comment: Eu recebo informações de uma simulação em forma de objeto de um programa que eu não tenho acesso a nada em relação a código. Esse objeto é uma instancia de uma classe da biblioteca deste programa, que não é do .NET. Esse objeto tem vários objetos dentro, e cada objeto desse é diferente do outro, com algumas coisas em comum, o que eu quero é pegar o nome dos atributos desses vários objetos, por exemplo, tenho um objeto do tipo válvula, nele eu tenho um inteiro chamado pressão, e um float chamado temperatura, eu quero poder imprimir "pressão" e "temperatura".

Comment: eu consegui retornar o tipo usando o método:
`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(Objeto)`
Porém este método retorna uma string, para fazer o reflection eu preciso que retorne no tipo System.Type.

Comment: Neste caso existe uma solução, mas depende de uma coisa: linguagem que a biblioteca COM foi escrita. Vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Eu consegui meio q forçando o reflexion, esqueci de responder meu post, vou fazer isto, não tinha visto seu ultimo comentário nem a edição da resposta...

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas e pelo tempo de vocês!